# cuando instalo react en visual studio me da B4210000:error:1C800066

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2Fparser: B4210000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Daniel Aleman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-19T22_15_40_973Z-debug-0.log
```